# how to select only clicked radio button and every other radio button should not be selected in dynamic addition

Tags: jquery

i am working on an asp.net website. Now i am adding radiobuttons dynamically so i can not group them. So i want to select only one radio button out of the list but due to dynamic nature evey radio button i select goes checked... 
please help me with jquery code.
i tried this but it didn't work...

```
    <script>
   $(document).ready(function () {

       $('.radios').click(function() {
           $('.radios').not(this).each(function () {

               $("input:radio").attr("checked", false);
           });
       });
   });

</script>
```

I am confused. please help. thanks.

Comment: _"adding radiobuttons dynamically so i can not group them"_ -Why not? You did give them the same `name`, right? http://jsfiddle.net/fZyQh/1/ (Or is there a particular browser where that doesn't work?)

Comment: Actually i want to do is to select only the clicked radio Button and rest of them should be unselected.

Comment: Yes. That's exactly how radio buttons naturally work: when you click one, all the rest in the same group, i.e., all the rest with the same `name`, get deselected. (In my fiddle I added two independent groups...)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 $("input:radio").attr("checked", false);


<script>
 $(document).ready(function () {

   $('.radios').click(function() {
        $("input:radio").attr("checked", false);
        $(this).attr("checked",true);
   });
  });

 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the radio button checked attribute is an all or nothing `checked=checked`, not a true/false value.

Have a look here for how jQuery handles the attribute: http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/